i have 4 mat tab labels in a mat tab group and i want to position 2 of them left and another 2 label to right how to achive this one for angular 17

I require one and two mat tab labels to position on left side and three and four mat-tab-labels on right side of the page. I tried giving margin but the the element is expanding all the way to right but rather is there any way ti position it to right side

Could you provide more details about how you've tried using margins? A code snippet of what you've attempted would be helpful!

.left-tabs {
  float: left; /* Position labels to the left */
  width: 50%; /* Adjust width as needed */
}

.right-tabs {
  float: right; /* Position labels to the right */
  width: 50%; /* Adjust width as needed */
}


The way to makes a mat-tab to the left it's simply add as style margin-leff:'auto'
Well, the problem is that it's not easy reach the "element". the mat-tabs have a class ".mat-mdc-tab.mdc-tab". So we can use getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-tab mdc-tab') to reach the "tabs"
Well, we can create a directive like
@Directive({
  standalone:true,
  selector:'[tab-right]'
})
export class TabToRight{
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  @Input('tab-right') set _(value:number)
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const tabs=this.el.nativeElement
                              .getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-tab mdc-tab');
      const el=tabs && tabs.item(value);
      if (el)
        (el as any).style["margin-left"]='auto';
    })
  }
}

And use simply like
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start" [tab-right]="1">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="sep" label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

See that the index begans in 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second one, ...
a stackblitz

Assign the @Input value [tab-right] to specify the number of tabs you want on the right side, and update the code below in your HTML file:
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start" [tab-right]="2">
</mat-tab-group> 

View_StackBlitz

why is the reason do you copy my answer?????

@Eliseo, Your answer might be correct, but you didn't assign the value of [tab-right] to the requirement for Saketh.
